# pseudo-random for index on an infinite strip

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I want to create a class that represents an infinite (2^32 can be considered as infinite) strip on which there are pseudo-random numbers. The interface should be very simple; the constructor should get an instance of `Random`; and  there should be a method to get the random number for an index.

Note that I don't want to store a huge lookup table and precalculate it; I want it to be done on the fly.

```
public class InfiniteRandomStrip {

    public InfiniteRandomStrip(Random r) {
       ...
    }

    public int getNumber(int index) {
        // magic code here
    }

}
```

Note that the code should pass the following test:

```
Random seed = new Random(123);
Random seed2 = new Random(123);
InfiniteRandomStrip strip = new InfiniteRandomStrip(seed);
InfiniteRandomStrip strip2 = new InfiniteRandomStrip(seed2);
int first = strip.getNumber(454); // consume the random
if(strip.getNumber(5) == strip2.getNumber(5) )
    System.out.println("TEST1 OK");
if(first == strip.getNumber(454) )
    System.out.println("TEST2 OK");
```

I've had no luck finding any example or algorithm for such a random list case. If such a problem has no solution, I will be glad to hear an explanation why.

Comment: okay, so what's your actual question? about code you already wrote for that matter?

Comment: I haven't implemented the code, I'm looking for that `magic code` that will be efficient enough

Comment: at 2k reputation, you should know stackoverflow is about "what have you tried". So: what have you tried?

Comment: I already mentioned, that I do not want to store a huge look up table. I'm looking for a "random access" to all the values of the strip.

Comment: no, what you've said is "here are my requirements, but I have zero code to show for it". So: what have you tried? where's your own attempt at solving this before asking others for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone the `Random` object in the `getNumber` method so that you start at the same seed each time. Then compute `nextInt` repeatedly until you get to the correct index.

```
int getNumber(int index) {
    Random r = this.seed.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; ++i) {
        r.nextInt();
    }
    return r.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: You never mentioned negative numbers in your question. I'm fairly certain you can't do it more efficiently without storing the sequence of numbers which you said could not be done in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class InfiniteRandomStrip {
    private final long seed;

    public InfiniteRandomStrip(Random r) {
        this.seed = r.nextLong();
    }

    public int getNumber(int index) {
        return new Random(seed ^ index).nextInt();
    }
}
```